# Blocking an independent process when transmitting data through a FIFO channel

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, mkfifo

I have 2 independent processes. I send 2 values to the second process to calculate their amount. This works, but now I need to return the value of the sum to the first process and this does not work anymore because of the lock. The second process is waiting for someone to do READ and it unlocks him. What are some ideas to return the value of the sum to the first process?
The code is below:

test.c:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f1,f2;
    int a = 4;
    int b = 3;
    int summ = 0;

    unlink("mk.fifo");

    if (mkfifo("mk.fifo", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
        error(0, errno, "mkfifo() error");

    f1 = open("mk.fifo", O_WRONLY);
    perror("Opening ");

    write(f1, &a, sizeof(int));
    write(f1, &b, sizeof(int));
    perror("Writing ");

    close(f1);

    f2 = open("mk.fifoSumm", O_RDONLY);
    perror("Opening ");

    read(f2, &summ, sizeof(int));
    perror("Reading ");

    close(f2);

    printf("Received string '%d'\n", summ);

    return 0;
}
```

test2.c:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f2,f1;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int summ = 0;

    f2 = open("mk.fifo", O_RDONLY);
    perror("Opening ");

    read(f2, &a, sizeof(int));
    read(f2, &b, sizeof(int));
    perror("Reading ");

    close(f2);

    printf("Received string '%d'\n", a);
    printf("Received string '%d'\n", b);

    summ = a + b;

    unlink("mk.fifoSumm");

    if (mkfifo("mk.fifoSumm", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
        error(0, errno, "mkfifo() error");

    f1 = open("mk.fifoSumm", O_WRONLY);
    perror("Opening ");

    write(f1, &summ, sizeof(int));
    perror("Writing ");
    close(f1);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: First issue I see, your first process is attempting to open a fifo which might not exist.

Comment: @TonyTannous No. He first creates fifo then opens

Comment: What if P1 opens `mk.fifoSumm` before `P2` creates it with `mkfifo` ?

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes you are right.

Comment: @TonyTannous So what should I do? Use synchronization tools?

Comment: For a start, put both mkfifo in process 1, and run it first. Check if this solves your problem.

Comment: @TonyTannous I am afraid that this will not solve the problem, because P1 will read before P2 writes to it.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. P1 will block until P2 writes. Once P2 opens fifo-1 for writing, P1 is awaken.

Comment: @TonyTannous I'm shocked, but it helped!!!